# Can't Copy Table Attribute using Mail Merge Script in Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Hello I'm new to google script, Is there a way to mail merge from google sheets to google docs that could copy table from template document. This is my script and it's not working.

The script works fine when there are no table attribute, but when I add script that could copy table, there's no output in targetDoc.

```
function copyDoc() {
  var sourceDocId = "ID sourceDoc";
  var targetDocId = "ID targetDoc";
  var docWorksheetId = "ID docWorksheet";

  var sourceDoc = DocumentApp.openById(sourceDocId);
  var targetDoc = DocumentApp.openById(targetDocId);
  var Workshet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(docWorksheetId).getSheetByName("data");
  
  var data = Workshet.getRange(2,1,Workshet.getLastRow()-1,12).getValues();
  var TemplateParagraph = sourceDoc.getBody().getParagraphs();

  data.forEach(function(r){
      createMailMerge(r[0],r[1],TemplateParagraph,targetDoc)
  });

  var totalElements = sourceDoc.getNumChildren();

function createMailMerge(columns_table1,columns_table2,TemplateParagraph,targetDoc){

  for( var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j ) {
    var body = targetDoc.getBody()
    var element = sourceDoc.getChild(j).copy();
    var type = element.getType();
    if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH ){
      targetDoc.getBody().appendParagraph(
        p
       .copy()
       .replaceText("{columns_table1}", columns_table1)
       .replaceText("{columns_table2}", columns_table2)
       
      );
      
    }
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE){
      targetDoc.getBody().appendTable(
      p
       .copy()
       .replaceText("{columns_table1}", columns_table1)
       .replaceText("{columns_table2}", columns_table2)
        
      );
      }
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM){
      targetDoc.getBody().appendListItem(
      p
       .copy()
       .replaceText("{columns_table1}", columns_table1)
       .replaceText("{columns_table2}", columns_table2)
       
      );
      }

  
}
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand about `The script works fine when there are no table attribute, but when I add script that could copy table, there's no output in targetDoc.`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your issue?

Comment: So, my former script is mail merge with only paragraph, no table in the template, but when there's a table, the script can't copy the table in target doc. Then I tried to make function that can copy table attribute but the script is not working. So maybe anyone could find what's my mistake in my code.

Comment: Try debugging your code - log `console.log(type)` before you conditional and see what type you're getting